# Is there a phrase that means "give a lot of attention to"?

Tags: phrase-request, idiomatic-language

Is there a phrase that means "give a lot of attention to"? I am trying to think of a good idiomatic sounding phrase I can use, but I can't really think of one. The best phrases I could come up with were: "give the spotlight to", "turn all eyes towards", but none of them works particularly well with "story" and "media".

For example:

> The media ___ the story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use the verb *followed*. One of that word's many meanings is:

> **[follow](https://www.wordnik.com/words/follow)** (*verb*) to watch or observe closely

In the context of media coverage, *follow* often implies watching the story develop and reporting on it often. For example, in [this piece](https://spectator.org/dye-markers-could-enhance-air-crash-searches/) about a plane crash, *The American Spectator* reads:

> For that entire time the media **followed** the story with daily updates that there was “nothing new to report.”

Another [legal blog](https://www.lettunichlawfirm.com/court-public-opinion-look-high-profile-cases-shocked-nation) discusses some very high-profile cases, and says:

> People jumped on the opportunity to tear her apart. For six weeks the media **followed** her trial closely and completely destroyed the woman's reputation for years to come.

And in a [piece](https://shelterforce.org/2005/07/01/a-victory-over-the-slumlords/) about a grass roots movement for decent housing, an author chronicled:

> The Tenants Union of Washington State went door to door to give tenants information on their rights. Eventually, TU organizers developed strong relationships with tenant leaders who worked with the group to ensure that **the media followed the story closely**.